# For /l loop failing to operate

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have created a loop to turn a decimal number into a binary number:

```
SET /P InputNum="Input Number: "

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    SET /A Output=%InputNum% %% 2
    SET BinaryArray[%%x]=%Output%
    SET /A InputNum /= 2
)

ECHO Binary Result: 
%BinaryArray[1]%%BinaryArray[2]%%BinaryArray[3]%%BinaryArray[4]%%BinaryArray[5]%
PAUSE
```

This isn't working though.  'Output' isn't being assigned its value, which means that the array isn't being populated and even the 'InputNum /= 2' isn't working for some reason. The output 'InputNum /= 2' doesn't seem to work at all.

I have this working in a non form:

```
SETLOCAL
SET /P InputNum="Input Number: "
SET /A Output1=%InputNum% %% 2
ECHO Bit 1: %Output1%

SET /A InputNum /= 2
SET /A Output2=%InputNum% %% 2
ECHO Bit 2: %Output2%

SET /A InputNum /= 2
SET /A Output3=%InputNum% %% 2
ECHO Bit 3: %Output3%

SET /A InputNum /= 2
SET /A Output4=%InputNum% %% 2
ECHO Bit 4: %Output4%

SET /A InputNum /= 2
SET /A Output5=%InputNum% %% 2
ECHO Bit 5: %Output5%

ECHO Binary Result:  %Output1%%Output2%%Output3%%Output4%%Output5%
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

But I cannot for the life of me get it even close to functional inside of a more elegant loop.  Am I missing some syntax that I just don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET /P InputNum="Input Number: "

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    SET /A Output=!InputNum! %% 2
    SET BinaryArray[%%x]=!Output!
    SET /A InputNum /= 2
)

ECHO Binary Result: 
%BinaryArray[1]%%BinaryArray[2]%%BinaryArray[3]%%BinaryArray[4]%%BinaryArray[5]%
PAUSE
```